# parsing var with blank spaces

Tags: bash, shell

I have a variable

```
some_var="a23=some value&p44=another_value&uw=possibly_another one"
```

and I want to convert it into several substrings one for each `=` (breaking at the `&`). So I would get

```
a23=some value
p44=another_value
uw=possibly_another one
```

If I run this code

```
for s in ${some_var//&/ };do echo $s;done
```

I get however

```
a23=some 
value
p44=another_value
uw=possibly_another
one
```

(it breaks at the empty spaces)

How can I run the loop so that it takes space into account?

Comment: `IFS='&' read -ra newvar <<< "a23=some value&p44=another_value&uw=possibly_another one"; echo "${newvar[0]}" "${newvar[1]}"`

Comment: `declare -p newvar` is handy for viewing arrays.

Comment: This technique is discussed at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`read` into an array using the '&' as field separator:

```
#!/bin/bash

some_var='a23=some value&p44=another_value&uw=possibly_another one'
IFS='&' read -r -a arr <<< "$some_var"
for s in "${arr[@]}"; do
    printf '%s\n' "$s"
done
```

A technique similar to yours also would work:

```
(IFS='&'; for s in $some_var; do printf '%s\n' "$s"; done)
```

Notice that it runs in a subshell not to mess up with the `IFS` of the current shell.

You may consider reading [this article](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/IFS) for detailed information on `IFS`.

Answer (score 4):

Populating an associative array with the argument=value pairs:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

uri_argstring='a23=some value&p44=another_value&uw=possibly_another one'

# Declare an empty associative array
declare -A uri_args=()

# Populate the associative array by reading key values pairs
# delimiting field by &, = or newline,
# delimiting records (argument=value or key=value pairs) with & or End Of File
while IFS=$'=&\n' read -r -d '&' k v; do
  # Add entry to associative array
  uri_args[$k]=$v
done <<<"$uri_argstring" # Feed here-string to the while loop reading

# Fancy printing
printf 'Argument=Value\n--------------\n'

# Iterate the keys from the uri_args associative array
for arg in "${!uri_args[@]}"; do
  value=${uri_args[$arg]}
  # Printout
  printf '%s=%s\n' "$arg" "$value"
done
```

Output:

```
Argument=Value
--------------
a23=some value
p44=another_value
```